# Is there a proper age for a chin up bar?

Tags: development, growth

My boy will be 8 in a month or so. We've been watching "American Ninja Warrior" and he's really impressed at watching people work out and train in gyms.

When I was a pre-teen (10-11) my parents got me a chin up bar.

Since he is under 10 and still developing:

Q: Should I wait to get a chin-up bar or is it safe at this age and it won't affect his physical development?

Comment: Don't have research to back this up... but my Dad got me a chin up bar when I was well under 8... and started my kids on the bars (using monkey bars from playset) at like 5-6. They required being held for safety, but that's because of lack of training, not age. Why this matters is that my Dad did a lot of research into physical training before I was born and knew what's safe and not.

Answer (score 1):

Well, almost by definition a chin up bar will affect his physical development -- that's the point, right?  It affects it in a positive way.  If it is set at the right height and proper supervision is given so that he doesn't try any "creative" means of using the chin up bar (yes, we've all been there and have found our own ways of doing things which we no longer think were such bright ideas), then what can be the harm? -- He's lifting his head above a bar using his own strength and against his own body weight.  If he were 3 foot tall and 300lbs, this would be quite a challenge and unlikely to succeed, but then I'd suggest you wouldn't be asking this particular question.